# Using git files

Tags: git, pack

Hi all I have cloned a git to get some source code and now I want to compile it
But I when I go to the directory where I have cloned , there are no files only ".pack" files. But I can see all files in git client. How do I extract the files from cloned git to compile them

Thank You

Comment: You wouldn't have done a `git clone --bare`, by any chance?

Comment: I used windows git client to clone the original git and did not pass any arguments

Comment: The GitHub for windows git client? (http://windows.github.com/)

Comment: So you actually used the command line interface with msysgit (http://msysgit.github.com/), right? Because  git-scm.com is not a gui, just a website. So, what command did you type to clone your repo?

Comment: no there is gui client at "http://www.git-scm.com/downloads"

Comment: I dowloaded a gui client from here http://www.git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: One listed here, then: http://www.git-scm.com/downloads/guis So GitHub for windows? Because otherwise, the main download link at http://www.git-scm.com/downloads is Git-1.7.11-preview20120620.exe, which is from msysgit, and is a command-line. It does contain `gitk` and `git-gui`, though. At this point, I think what would help is for you to edit your question, and **put a screenshot** of how you have cloned your repo through that gui of yours.

Comment: can you give commands to download git with unpacked files so that I can download it correct this time

Comment: Any error message? Is your disk full so it cannot checkout any file?

Comment: I have added an answer to illustrate the right `git clone` command.

Answer (score 0):

From [`git clone` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), and "[Git Basics - Getting a Git Repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository)", a simple:

```
git clone url/of/your/repo
```

is enough to clone a git as a non-bare repo, that is with its working tree filled with the files from the default branch (usually the `master` one)

[image: full non-bare repo]

That would be what you see at the left ("Working Directory").
A `git clone --bare url/of/your/repo` would only produce the right part ("Repository"), where you would only see packed files.

---

Now, if you did clone the repo, and still don't see any file (only the .git directory), that can happen with certain repos, like illustrated [by this thread](http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg45937.html).

In that case, a **`git checkout master`** (after the `git clone`, and from within the root dir of your repo) should be enough to restore the full content of the working tree.

If you want to checkout directly from a specific branch:

```
git checkout -t -b android-3.0 origin/android-3.0
```

That will link your local branch to the remote one, as well as fill the working tree with the content of the files for that branch.